# Reference to a publication about Gazebo (new)

Tags: gazebo, simulation, gazebo-ignition

For an academic paper we'd like to find a system paper describing Gazebo (formerly known as Ignition).

For Gazebo classic, there was this publication:

> N. Koenig et al., “Design and use paradigms for Gazebo, an open-source
> multi-robot simulator,” in Int. Conf. Intell. Robots Syst., vol. 3, 2004,
> pp. 2149–2154 vol.3.

Is there a similar publication for the new Gazebo? And if not, what would be the preferred way to cite it according to the Gazebo maintenance team?